# How can I tell on which commit a file was merged into my branch?

Tags: github

I've accidentally merged files into my branch. I don't know on which commit this happened.

Is there a way I can look at when a file was committed to my branch?

Answer (score 1):

You can view each commit and see which files were changed (as well as how they were changed).  You can also browse your repository at the time of each commit, if you want to see which file versions were in there.

To see your list of commits, add `/commits` to your project URL.  For example, if your GitHub username is "bob" and your project is named "myproject" you would go to:

`https://github.com/bob/myproject/commits`

You can also get to the commits list by clicking **Graphs** at the top of your project page, then selecting the link under your username labeled **xx commits** where "xx" is the number of commits.